# How to create a list of factories with one value incremented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am using `factory_girl_rails` together with `RSpec`.

I want x `Placement` created and inserted into a array with one of the attributes incrementing its value.

I have a version that is working, but I would like to make use of factory girl as much as possible.

My working solution

```
def create_placements(x)
  x.times.map { |i| create :placement, foo: i }
end
```

Can it be achieved with factory girl only? Something like `create_list :placement, x, foo: 1..x` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FactoryGirl` has the method `*_list`, e. g. `create_list` - more info [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/FactoryGirl/Syntax/Methods#create_list-instance_method).

However it only accepts one set of data and uses it for all of its 'subjects', so if you wanted each of them to differ in some way, I think your loop is the best approach here.

Comment: Okey, I guess I will have to settle with my solution then. 
If I remove map the code will return the last created placement rather than an array

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but you can do that with [sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences).

In your case, in the file where you defined the factory `placement`, you should add as a child the factory `placement_foo_increment` or whatever the name you want.

Then the factory should be:

```
factory :placement_foo_increment do
  sequence(:foo) { |n| n - 1 }
end
```

The `- 1` is there becase `n` starts from 1, and in your code it starts from zero.